# Why do Entries have different text using the same Variable?

Tags: python, tkinter

Basically, I was just experimenting with tkinter and decided to write this useless code:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
var = tk.IntVar(value=1)


class SmallClass(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, special_var: tk.IntVar, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.label = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=special_var, font=('', 20))
        self.label.pack()
        self.bind('<Enter>', lambda event: (print('value in the Entry: ', self.label.get()),
                                            print("value set in Variable: ", self.getvar(self.label['textvariable']))))

        special_var.trace('w', lambda *options: special_var.set(special_var.get()*2))


SmallClass(var).pack()
SmallClass(var).pack()
SmallClass(var).pack()
SmallClass(var).pack()
SmallClass(var).pack()
SmallClass(var).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I tkink it's better to run this code and see what happens. I am just trying to understand why it works in such a strange way. It looks like when I change `variable` in one place, it does this small lambda function for each class and  multiplies the current value by 2 several times. So, `Entry` will start to have different values even though they are all using the same `textvariable`. At first, I thought it would cause an error, but there were no errors at all. Maybe  this is due to update issues, but I have checked that `entry`s actually have the text you see, and it is not equal to `textvariable`s value.

So maybe you have some idea why this behaves in the way it does? Is it a tkinter bag or I just did't get something?

Also, you can modify the code and move the line

```
special_var.trace('w', lambda *options: special_var.set(special_var.get()*2))
```

outside the class and so change to

```
var.trace('w', lambda *options: var.set(var.get()*2))
```

This way the function will run once but still won't work as "expected".

Comment: During the execution of a write trace on a Tk Var, further trace calls are disabled - otherwise, setting the same Var from within the trace would be an infinite recursion!  However, this also disables the read trace that the Entries use to update themselves when the Var changes, so they get out of sync.

Comment: @jasonharper oh, I see, thanks for explanation. Is there a way to force other widgets to update without disabling the read function during the `set`? Like how to fix this? Or maybe just don't set the variable in the way I'm doing it?